# Bulk ETH address checker

Tags: python, python-3.x, ethereum, pycrypto, cryptoapi

I used https://github.com/corpetty/py-etherscan-api,
This is my simple script, for checking eth addresses for balance, but it very slow, how I can make this script much more faster?

```
from etherscan.accounts import Account
import sys 
import os
list = "adr.txt"
with open(list, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        address = line.rstrip()
        api = Account(address=address, api_key='YourApiKey')
        balance = api.get_balance()
        print(address, (int(balance) / 1000000000000000000), file=open("result.txt", "a"))
```